# Find the point on the graph of $y= \sqrt{x}$ that is nearest to the point $(p, 0)$ if (i) $p > 1/2$; and (ii) $0 < p < 1/2$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the point on the graph of $y= \sqrt{x}$ that is nearest to the point $(p, 0)$ if (i) $p > 1/2$; and (ii) $0 < p < 1/2$.

I could use some help for part ii. I found the derivative of the distance in part i to be $$\frac{x-p+1/2}{(x^2+x-2xp+p^2)^{-{1/2}}}$$ However, I know that $x = p-1/2$ makes the function undefined. How would I find the smallest $p$-value for which the function is defined?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Did you mean $\dfrac{x - p + \frac{1}{2}}{(x^2 + x - 2xp + p^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$?

Comment: Given a point $(p,0)$, it is asked to find the point of $y=\sqrt x$ such that the distance $d((p,0),(x,\sqrt x)$ is minimun. The discussion about $p$ becomes naturally.